# IOS 16 UIPanGestureRecognizer change brightness with pan gesture

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer, brightness, ios16

This function works fine in iOS 15 but not in iOS 16.
In iOS 16 even though you drag your finger only adds or subtracts once.
Thank you very much for your reply

```swift
 @objc func pan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.changed || recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.ended {
            let velocity:CGPoint = recognizer.velocity(in: self.view)
            if velocity.y > 0 {
                UIScreen.main.brightness -= 0.01
            } else {
                UIScreen.main.brightness += 0.01
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The minimum number it supports is ```0.025001```

Comment: What you're doing is not how to do a pan gesture recognizer. All you are doing is checking the _direction_ of the finger movement — you are not examining the _position_ of the finger relative to its starting place. So even if your code is called multiple times, which I doubt because you are never adjusting the position, you are only getting these tiny meaningless increments of the brightness which effectively do nothing.